# Show defined table content based on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a problem not sure how to solve it. I want to create a formula which will display the content of the table based on cell value.

I have for e.g two tables Box1, Box2

```
Box1    Box2

Name1   Name1
Name2   Name2
Name3   Name3
```

I defined the table name Box1 and Box2, now I would like to achieve something like this

```
=IF(A1="text",Box1,no match)
```

When I type in cell A1 text will display me the whole table content in column B

Thank you for all help.

Comment: a) What version of Excel are you running? b) Does this have to work on other versions? If so, what is the earliest? c) Do you want to show the contents of the Box2 table? If so, how? If not, why was it even mentioned?

Comment: How did you manage to define the Table names as `Box1` and `Box2`. Those represent cell addresses in Excel 2010, and would usually be flagged as invalid names.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Excel 2007 as well IIRC.

Comment: @Jeeped.  Yes, true.  He added an `excel-2010` tag while I was creating my comment, so I restricted my comment to that version.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you managed to name your Table `Box1` since that should have been flagged as illegal (since `BOX1` is a cell address in Excel-2010).

Assuming that statement was incorrect, a formula could be:

```
B1: =IFERROR(IF($A$1="text", INDEX(_Box1,ROWS($1:1)),""),"")
```

and fill down as far as needed.

Comment: Ha! I didn't catch the BOX1 cell reference conflict until you pointed it out. Good catch.